# Bootstrap affix plugin fails sometimes at the bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

[image]I need order summary sidebar to be fixed like the one in the picture attached the sidebar should stop as indicated in the picture but it goes below the footer sometimes.

I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0 affix plug-in to fix order summary in sidebar on checkout page of my opencart store.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true);
                var c =  $('.custom-footer').outerHeight();
                var f = $('.full-width').outerHeight();
                var footerHeight =c + f+ 60;
                $('#summary-div').affix({
                  offset: {
                    top: 270,
                    bottom: footerHeight // using bottom value like this  never always makes the order summary div to overlap the footer
                   //bottom :455 // I get affixed sidebar when i use bottom value as 455 but it sometimes overlaps the footer 
                  }
                }).on('affix.bs.affix', function() { // before affix
                  $(this).css({    
                    'width': $(this).outerWidth() // variable widths
                  });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #summary-div.affix{
              position: fixed;
              top: 0px;
              width: 28.8%;
            }
            .affix-top{
              position: static;
            }

            .affix-bottom{
              position:absolute;
              bottom:auto !important;
            }
        </style>
```

I have updated the question and image.

Comment: try setting the $('.custom-footer').outerHeight(true) as a variable outside the affix. I wonder if the JS cant keep up with the browser trying to return that height param that quickly.

Comment: @crazymatt can you please now look i have added an image and changed my question's details to elaborate it more, please help

Comment: its impossible to tell what the issue is with the little code that is supplied. Anyway you can reproduce the issue in a [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or provide more code? Also have you tried adding the code in the HTML instead of through the JS, just to see if the issue still happens?

Comment: @crazymatt i could not implement the issue in js.fiddle
https://mdpocket.com/
this is the store's website . I request you sir please make an effort for me and go the website register an account and add some items in the cart and go to checkout page. And Please suggest me how to make order summary sidebar floating.
P.S : On live website I have not implemented any code for floating sidebar. I just want you to go to website and see if you can figure out something. That would be a great favour sir

Comment: not even a single line of source code!!! how you are expecting to give an answer!!!

Comment: should i add code for order summary ? I am confused.
i know i am being juvenile but can you figure out by going to the actual website 
https://mdpocket.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Check Working Demo **[HERE](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ozZaxQ)**

JS:

```
var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true);
var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight() + 60;
$('#account-overview-container').affix({
  offset: {
    top: headerHeight,
    bottom: footerHeight
  }
}).on('affix.bs.affix', function() { // before affix
  $(this).css({    
    'width': $(this).outerWidth() // variable widths
  });
});
```

Comment: i have changed the image , it shows the issue i get
Plus i have used your code it also has the same issue ,

Comment: I need the order summary to be in level or left div and i get this but sometimes order summary div overlaps the footer. I don't know what is the reason for that

Comment: @harronejaz try with latest version of bootstrap. In demo its working fine.

Comment: I have bootstrap 3.0.0 and i am not allowed to change the version, any other idea?

Comment: Try setting `body{ position:relative;}`

Comment: you can checkout this [Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4647). It might hep you.

Comment: can you please just visit https://mdpocket.com/ and register an account and add some products in cart and go to checkout page.
There you will see that the content in right side loaded dynamically in panels , I don't have any idea how to deal with that as when i click continue in first panel and the data loads in second panel it changes the document height , and i think that causes the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124724/discussion-between-jyoti-pathania-and-harron-ejaz).